# awk to count 1's 2's 3's Multiple Column

Tags: awk

Would like to know how to count based on $1 & $2 combination , number of 1's , 2's ,3's and 4's occurrences  from $3,$4,$5,$6 and $7

Sample Input

```
Name,Date,XXX,YYY,ZZZ,AAA,BBB
ABC,19-10-2020,2,NA,4,3,NA
ABC,19-10-2020,NA,3,NA,NA,4
ABC,18-10-2020,1,NA,4,4,NA
ABC,18-10-2020,NA,3,NA,NA,4
CDE,19-10-2020,1,NA,4,3,NA
CDE,19-10-2020,NA,2,NA,NA,4
CDE,18-10-2020,3,3,4,3,3
CDE,18-10-2020,NA,3,NA,NA,4
FGH,18-10-2020,4,4,4,4,4
```

Desired Output

```
Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4
ABC,19-10-2020,0,1,2,2
ABC,18-10-2020,1,0,1,3
CDE,19-10-2020,1,1,1,2
CDE,18-10-2020,0,0,5,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,0,5
```

I have tried like below command with un-successful output. Please help on this.

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=","; print $1,$2}'  | awk -F"," 'BEGIN {count=0} {key=$0; a[key]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    maxVal = 4
}
NR > 1 {
    key = $1 OFS $2
    keys[key]
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        cnt[key,$i]++
    }
}
END {
    printf "Name%sDate%s", OFS, OFS
    for (i=1; i<=maxVal; i++) {
        printf "CountOF %d%s", i, (i<maxVal ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (key in keys) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (i=1; i<=maxVal; i++) {
            printf "%d%s", cnt[key,i], (i<maxVal ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4
ABC,19-10-2020,0,1,2,2
ABC,18-10-2020,1,0,1,3
CDE,19-10-2020,1,1,1,2
CDE,18-10-2020,0,0,5,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,0,5
```

the `for (key in keys)` in the END can shuffle the order of output lines. If that's an issue there's various tweaks to solve it. It'd also be trivial to calculate `maxVal` rather than hard-coding it to 4.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  print "Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4"
}
FNR>1{
  till=""
  delete arr
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
    ind[$1 OFS $2]
    if($i!="NA"){ arr[$i]++; max_till=(max_till>$i?max_till:$i) }
  }
  till=(NF-3)
  for(j=1;j<=till;j++){
    value[$1 OFS $2 OFS j]+=arr[j]
  }
}
END{
  for(k in ind){
    printf("%s,",k)
    for(i=1;i<=max_till;i++){
      printf("%d%s",(value[k OFS i]?value[k OFS i]:0),i==max_till?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4
ABC,19-10-2020,0,1,2,2
ABC,18-10-2020,1,0,1,3
CDE,19-10-2020,1,1,1,2
CDE,18-10-2020,0,0,5,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,0,5
```

Comment: The array use is a tidy approach. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

You never need to call awk more than once. You simply sum the occurrences and output, e.g.

```
awk -F, '
    BEGIN { 
        OFS=","
        print "Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4"
        ones=twos=threes=fours=0
    }
    last && last != $1" "$2 {
        print $1,$2,ones,twos,threes,fours
        ones=twos=threes=fours=0
        last = $1" "$2
    }
    FNR > 1 {
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
            $i=="1" && ones++
            $i=="2" && twos++
            $i=="3" && threes++
            $i=="4" && fours++
        }
        last=$1" "$2
    }
    END {
        print $1,$2,ones,twos,threes,fours
    }
' file.csv
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F, '
>     BEGIN {
>         OFS=","
>         print "Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4"
>         ones=twos=threes=fours=0
>     }
>     last && last != $1" "$2 {
>         print $1,$2,ones,twos,threes,fours
>         ones=twos=threes=fours=0
>         last = $1" "$2
>     }
>     FNR > 1 {
>         for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
>             $i=="1" && ones++
>             $i=="2" && twos++
>             $i=="3" && threes++
>             $i=="4" && fours++
>         }
>         last=$1" "$2
>     }
>     END {
>         print $1,$2,ones,twos,threes,fours
>     }
> ' file.csv
Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4
ABC,18-10-2020,0,1,2,2
CDE,19-10-2020,1,0,1,3
CDE,18-10-2020,1,1,1,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,5,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,0,5
```

Comment: Doing it without using arrays is surely more efficient ++

Answer (score 3):

This awk should also work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
}
NR > 1 {
   k=$1 OFS $2
   arr[k]
   for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i)
      ++freq[k OFS $i]
}
END {
   print "Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4"
   for (i in arr)
      print i, freq[i OFS 1]+0, freq[i OFS 2]+0,freq[i OFS 3]+0,freq[i OFS 4]+0
}' file.csv
```

```
Name,Date,CountOF 1,CountOF 2,CountOF 3,CountOF 4
ABC,19-10-2020,0,1,2,2
ABC,18-10-2020,1,0,1,3
CDE,19-10-2020,1,1,1,2
CDE,18-10-2020,0,0,5,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,0,5
```

Comment: The array and function use is a very nice touch!

Comment: Oh yes that's right. I should have thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk using array and split function

```
$ awk -F, ' BEGIN {OFS="," } NR>1 { k=$1 OFS $2;$1=$2=""; a[k]=a[k] OFS $0  } END { for(i in a) { printf("%s",i); for(j=1;j<=4;j++) { n=split(a[i],t,j); printf(",%s",n-1) } print "" } }  ' count_1234.txt
ABC,19-10-2020,0,1,2,2
ABC,18-10-2020,1,0,1,3
CDE,19-10-2020,1,1,1,2
CDE,18-10-2020,0,0,5,2
FGH,18-10-2020,0,0,0,5
$
```

Breaking up in multiple lines for readability.

```
awk -F, ' BEGIN {OFS="," } 
NR>1 { k=$1 OFS $2;$1=$2=""; a[k]=a[k] OFS $0  } 
END { 
      for(i in a) 
      {    
            printf("%s",i); 
            for(j=1;j<=4;j++) 
             { 
                n=split(a[i],t,j); 
                printf(",%s",n-1) 
             } 
           print "" 
     } 
   }  '
```